# How to update openGL in VMware?

Tags: graphics, vmware, opengl

Is it possible to update openGL and graphics card drivers to the latest version in Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit inside VMware?

If yes, How !?

P.S. I have already read the similar articles in the forum, but unfortunately they are not about VMware. So please do not mark this as dupl-icate! Thanks.

Comment: Please explain how updating Ubuntu inside a vmware session is different from a normal Ubuntu? I don't think they are ...

Comment: @Rinzwind, It is different because VMware accesses the hardware in a different way. So Ubuntu does not have real direct access to hardware. It's virtualization.

Comment: but that has nothing to do with updating the system. Nothing at all.

Comment: So please help me how to do this. I'm a beginner :(